# Get rid "Start voice call?" confirmation dialog on WhatsApp voice call

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, popup

Every time I want to call someone on WhatsApp, a popup appears asking:

[image]

> Start voice call?
>
> <kbd>Cancel</kbd> <kbd>Call</kbd>

When I click on the call button, clearly I want to call that person, this pop-up is an unnecessary extra step.

How can I get rid of this pop-up?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this appears 5 times and then disappears by itself. You cannot turn it off.
The 5 counts are only if you press "call" 5 times, not "cancel".
Simplest way - find someone you don't mind them being notified a few times of a missed call and call them 5 times.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).